# Camel RSS component and Choice filtering

Tags: apache-camel

I have a camel route that looks like this:

```
        from("rss:" + RSS_URL)
        .marshal().rss()
        .choice()
            .when(xpath("//item/guid/text()[contains(.,'4552')]"))
                .log("Cool")
                .to("seda:end")
            .otherwise()
                .log("Other message")
                .to("seda:end");
```

When I check the log I see exactly one message

> [example.com/feed/] route1                         INFO  Other message

If I replace the `choice` with a `filter` directive and throw a `process` in there, my filter does work:

```
        from("rss:" + RSS_URL)
        .marshal().rss()
        .filter().xpath("//item/guid/text()[contains(.,'4552')]")
        .process(new Processor() {
        @Override
        public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
            System.out.println("Got Here");
        }
    })
        .to("seda:end");
```

Sure enough, I see "Got Here" in my console.  To make matters even worse, if I replace my `process(...)` with just `log("Cool")` I get messages in the log stating the filter matched false and I don't see "Cool" anywhere...  I don't get that.

Can anyone tell what's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version of camel are you using?
Did you try to use endChoice() DSL to mark the block of Choice?

```
from("rss:" + RSS_URL)
    .marshal().rss()
    .choice()
        .when(xpath("//item/guid/text()[contains(.,'4552')]"))
            .log("Cool")
            .to("seda:end")
        .endChoice()
        .otherwise()
            .log("Other message")
        .endChoice()
        .to("seda:end");
```

Comment: v2.11.1, is it possible it's because after marshalling the body is just byte string and not a dom?

Comment: thanks, I used `endChoice()` and also `?splitEntries=true` in my RSS_URL and it seemed to make all the difference